# querying all sensor values for a machine

Tags: cumulocity

I have a simulator with 5 custom measurements sent every 5 minutes. I would like to get the results of these custom measurements based on the name of the simulator, can you please assist me on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly query measurements by the device name (only with the device ID) so you have to do two queries:

Step 1:
Query for the device based on the name to get the ID:

```
/inventory/managedObjects?fragmentType=c8y_IsDevice&text={device_name}
```

Step 2:
Query for measurements based on source ID

```
/measurement/measurements?source={device ID}&dateFrom={...}&dateTo={...}&revert=true&pageSize=5
```

I added a couple more query parameters. I guess dateFrom/dateTo is clear. The revert parameter will give you the latest measurements first and the pageSize limits the results to 5. So the query should give you the latest 5 measurements for the device which should result in one for each of you 5 measurements

Comment: Thanks for the answer tyr. i have the device id but i want to query using the (select - from syntax) event processing instead of using REST api can you elaborate on that?

Comment: If we are talking about event processing this is a totally different topic. Keep in mind that although the syntax looks like SQL this is not a query language. If you need to query something from database from within event processing take a look at http://cumulocity.com/guides/event-language/functions/